# Abort trap: 6 in protocol extension with typealias definitions

Tags: swift, protocol-extension

I have the following code that compiles and runs in Xcode 9.2 Standard Build System and `swift build -c release` but it does not compile and gives `abort trap: 6` when build project with `New Build System (Preview)` or `swift build`

```
import Foundation

protocol RestProtocol {
    associatedtype PostModelType: Codable
    associatedtype GetModelType: Codable
    associatedtype PostResponseType: Codable
}

extension RestProtocol {
    static func consume(with: [String: Any],
                        completion: @escaping (GetModelType?, Error?) -> Void) {
        completion(nil, nil)
    }

    static func produce(with: PostModelType,
                        completion: @escaping (PostResponseType?, Error?) -> Void) {
        completion(nil, nil)
    }
}

struct Model<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var code: Int?
    var message: String?
    var success: Bool?
    var result: T?
}

struct Service: RestProtocol {
    typealias PostModelType = DetailsModel
    typealias GetModelType = Model<DetailsModel>
    typealias PostResponseType = Model<DetailsModel>
}

struct DetailsModel: Codable {
    var response: String?
}

Service.consume(with: ["Key": "value"]) { (response, error) in
    print("This compiles in Xcode and swift build -c release but gives Abort trap: 6 in swift build")
}
```

Thanks for the helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was an issue in build system messing up with case sensitive file naming in Xcode.
Having files such as `Account.swift` and `account.swift` in the same module would cause the error.